# Viewing Hyper-V VM without connecting

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

Is there a way to see the screen of a Hyper-V vm without actually connecting to the vm? Like the small preview screen at the bottom left hand side on the Hyper-V Manager window.

I need to monitor the activity on one of my vm's, but I don't want to disconnect the current user.

Comment: What do you mean with "activity"?

Comment: I mean seeing what is being done on the vm. Seeing the output of the "monitor"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much everything you see in the Hyper-V Manager is fetched through WMI.  You can get the screen thumbnail that way, too.  Here's a blog post on how to do it:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2016/05/27/capturing-a-hyper-v-vm-screen-to-a-file/

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Just the "Msvm_VideoHead" wasn't available so I had to set a custom resolution.